# (node:25372) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**I'm new with node.js and javascript and wanted to code a Discord Bot for my server. I'm working on Embeds and get stuck. Whenever I want to run my code, this comes up here**:

```
(node:15928) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Lusor\OneDrive\Desktop\dcbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Lusor\OneDrive\Desktop\dcbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Lusor\OneDrive\Desktop\dcbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\Lusor\OneDrive\Desktop\dcbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:171:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/872588467211763804/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

**And here is my code:**

```
const { Client, Attachment, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "rules",
    description: "Embeds!",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e38f0e')
        .setTitle('Rules')
        .setDescription("Welcome in Valhalla's Game Center! Please read the Rules caredfully!")
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: 'u200B', value: 'u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here'},
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here'},
        )
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');

         message.channel.send(newEmbed);

        

    }
}
```

**I literally tried everything and couldn't find something helpful.**

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward. Use `messageCreate` instead of `message`

Comment: The error that is stopping your code isn't `DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated.`, it's `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Comment: which `message` should i replace ? @Elitezen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the technique for sending an "embedded message" to a channel (from [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor)) is

```
channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

So, for your code, try changing

```
message.channel.send(newEmbed);
```

to

```
message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed] });
```

Comment: omg thank youu so much , it works finally ♥

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer to your question, even if it wasn't what was causing your problem.

Where you have

```
client.on('message', message =>......
```

change the `'message'` to `'messageCreate'`.
You don't have to change any more messages to messageCreate, just that one. It was bothering me too.