# Is there an alternative way to avoid that error?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
module.exports = { 
    name: 'command',
    description: "Embeds!",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#304281')
        .setTitle('Rules')
        const newLocal = 'This is an embed for the server';
        setDescription(newLocal)
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Rule 1', value: 'Be good'},
            {name: 'Rule 2 ', value: 'Be polite'},
        )
        .setFooter('Make sure to check out that')

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

i need your help cause it prints me that error in terminal (i am new)
(node:3712) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. If your code run just fine, you can ignore it. If you want to get rid of it, just follow what the warning says. It pretty much explains itself.

Comment: include to  the begin --> module.exports = { 
but i cant write it to the above code

Comment: @RickyMo my code runs well but embeds doesn't appear to the discord after the writing of command .. thats the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(node:25372) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761211/node25372-deprecationwarning-the-message-event-is-deprecated-use-messagecre)

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error just a warn. But you can just replace the event `client.on('message', async () => ...)` with `client.on('messageCreate', async () => ...)`