# The message event is deprecated use messageCreate instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I am trying to update my discord bot from v12 to v13, the bot is running and all commands are loaded in the console, but this notification appears at the bottom and none of my commands are working. As an example, I shared a command with you, is there something missing or need to fix? I would be glad if you help.

[image]

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ayarlar = require('../ayarlar.json');
exports.run = async (client, messageCreate, args) => {

let target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
messageCreate.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor(`${ayarlar.embedcolor}`)
.setAuthor(target.tag, target.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
.setTitle('Avatar')
.setImage(target.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 })));
                     
}; 
exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: false,
  aliases: ['av'],
  permLevel: 0
};
 
exports.help = {
  name: 'avatar'
};
```

**head of main.js**

```
const {Client, Collection, Intents} = require("discord.js");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const ayarlar = require("./ayarlar.json");
var Jimp = require("jimp");
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const db = require("quick.db");
const ms = require("ms");

const client = new Client({intents: [3805]});

const Discord = require('discord.js');

require("dotenv").config;

module.exports = client;

client.discord = Discord;
client.commands = new Collection();
client.slashCommands = new Collection();
client.config = require('./ayarlar.json');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(node:25372) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761211/node25372-deprecationwarning-the-message-event-is-deprecated-use-messagecre)

Comment: i tried this and that's how it is in my command but that didn't run the command :(

Answer (score -1):

It's not in the code you have shown here, but somewhere in the code is something like this:

```
client.on("message", ......
```

That is the event that is deprecated. You need to change it to:

```
client.on("messageCreate", ......
```